# Get value from one class to use it in another class (java)

Tags: java

I have two classes

in class ABC

```
double a = 0.5 
public double lala()
{
     return a;
}
```

I want use it in another class, let us say class DEF

```
ABC abc;
double baba = abc.lala();
```

But it says that java.lang.NullPointerException, any idea? Thx

```
public class AdapterDB 
{ 
        double cal;
    double rcarbohydrate;
    double rfat;
    double rprotein;

    public AdapterDB(double cal, double rcarbohydrate, double rfat, double rprotein, Context ctx)
    {
        this.cal = cal;
        this.rcarbohydrate = rcarbohydrate;
        this.rfat = rfat;
        this.rprotein = rprotein;
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper (context);        
    }

        public double Calorie()
    {
        return cal;
    }

    public double Carbohydrate()
    {
        return rcarbohydrate;
    }

    public double Protein()
    {
        return rprotein;
    }

    public double Fat()
    {
        return rfat;
    }

}
```

Here is my code for class ABC, and I want to use some of them at another class >_<

Comment: now its much better question than previous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allocate ABC in memory, otherwise it points to `null`, hence NullPointerException:

```
ABC abc = new ABC();
double baba = abc.lala();
```

**Edit**: Ok, in case ABC does not have a zero-argument constructor like:

```
public ABC() { }
```

you have two options to solve your problem. Either add one and inside give default values to your other fields. Like:

```
public AdapterDB()
{
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper (context);        
}
```

Or, modify the creation of the object like:

```
double p1 = <some value>;
double p2 = <some value>;
double p3 = <some value>;
double p4 = <some value>;
Context ctx = new Context(); // don't know what this does.
ABC abc = new ABC(p1, p2, p3, p4, context);
double baba = abc.lala();
```

Comment: I can't use ABC abc = new ABC(); because it require argument, I just can use ABC abc;

Comment: @Michelle. You mean a constructor argument? Please post the code of class ABC.

Comment: double a = <some value>;  some Value of what? for ur information, cal, rfat, rprotein, and rcarbohydrate is from another class too :D that i want to passing it into another class again

Comment: @Michelle Any value that you need. If must be a numeric value. Like 1.2 or 0.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize that `abc` reference before using it:

```
ABC abc = new ABC();
// then use it
```

Comment: I can't use ABC abc = new ABC(); because it require argument, I just can use ABC abc;

Comment: Not sure I got it... The constructor requires arguments ? Like `new ABC(arg1, arg2)` ? Or the `ABC abc` reference that you're using is an argument for your method ? In either case, you cannot bypass the instantiation: `new ABC(/*whatever arguments*/)`

Answer (score 1):

you didn't initialize the abc object of the ABC class that's why. you need to initialize first abc object like this way

```
ABC abc = new ABC();
double baba = abc.lala();
```

if you want that without creating any object of an class and used that class of member used static keyword like this way

```
class ABC{
   private static double a = 0.5;
   public static double lala(){
         return a;
   }
}
```

and you can access that method like this way

```
ABC.lala();
```

but for that you must define the other member with the static keyword which you want to used into static method

Comment: I can't use ABC abc = new ABC(); because it require argument, I just can use ABC abc;

Comment: just it, I want use value from one class to another class, should be simply but it can't work, i am confused @.@

Comment: @Michelle when any constructor was define the you need to pass the value at object creation time of an class. () it's define the class constructor. if you post the ABC class code the I easily explain to you how you can used it

Comment: sorry m not able to open that link it's block for me can post this code into your question at end